# String manipulation in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using a script to move a particular file from one location to another location, which retrieves that file name from a log file. When I run this command in the shell prompt, it's okay.

**`Example: When I run this command:`**

```
tail -2 /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/DirectPayOutErrorLog.log |
    grep 'MESSAGE: SQL Exception:Invalid column index' |
    sed 's/.*FILE NAME: //;s/].*//;s/ /\\ /g'
```

the output is :

```
userList1305816669650_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_WEEL\ ONE\ PAYOUT.xls
```

**`However, when I run this command:`**

```
cp `tail -2 /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/DirectPayOutErrorLog.log |
    grep 'MESSAGE: SQL Exception:Invalid column index' |
    sed 's/.*FILE NAME: //;s/].*//;s/ /\\ /g'` /pretupshome/
```

the output is:

```
cp: cannot stat `userList1305816669650_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_WEEL':
    No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `ONE': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `PAYOUT.xls': No such file or directory
```

**`Actually, I do the same in script which is like:`**

```
fname=`tail -2 /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/DirectPayOutErrorLog.log |
    grep 'MESSAGE: SQL Exception:Invalid column index' |
    sed 's/.*FILE NAME: //;s/].*//;s/ /\\ /g'`

mv /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/BulkComissionPayout/UploadOffline/$fname
    /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/BulkComissionPayout/Errorfile/
```

But it can not move this file, showing the same error in above.

Kindly help me: how can I move the same in a script?

Answer (score 5):

Try out putting it inside quotes:

```
fname=`tail -2 /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/DirectPayOutErrorLog.log |
    grep 'MESSAGE: SQL Exception:Invalid column index' |
    sed 's/.*FILE NAME: //;s/].*//'`

mv "/pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/BulkComissionPayout/UploadOffline/$fname"
    /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/BulkComissionPayout/Errorfile/
```

The path `/pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/BulkComissionPayout/UploadOffline/$fname` has spaces when resolved.

I think putting this statement inside quotes should work.

Comment: Doesn't the first line also need quotes around the command substitution?

Comment: I don't think its needed. Whatever it should print as output, I believe it will copy it in `fname`. Now while using fname, if it has spaces, it should be within double quotes.

Comment: No It's not Working After giving in double quote it showing in same error

Comment: Could you please provide the output of `tail -2 /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/DirectPayOutErrorLog.log |
    grep 'MESSAGE: SQL Exception:Invalid column index'`

Comment: Try removing `s/ /\\ /g`. Spaces should be taken care by adding double quotes only

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not do the space replacement (`s/ /\\ /g`) if you want to execute your command this way.

Comment: sh bulkerror.sh 
Fri May 20 15:07:40 IST 2011
ls: /pretupsvar/pretups_weblogs/BulkComissionPayout/UploadOffline/userList1305816669650_PB_PBZONE_DLMP_RLMP_ETOPUP_WEEL: No such file or directory
ls: ONE: No such file or directory
ls: PAYOUT.xls: No such file or directory

Comment: Actually I don't know where the `ls` is coming from. I don't see it in your script extract.